# Extended property if not available

Tags: ios, swift, runtime, availability

With Swift 2, Apple introduced the API availability checking which allows one to execute certain code only on a specified version or later, like this:

```
if #available(iOS 9, *) {
    // use UIStackView
} else {
    // use fallback
}
```

For instance, iOS 9.0 introduces the `localizedUppercaseString` property:

```
/// An uppercase version of the string that is produced using the current
/// locale.
public var localizedUppercaseString: String { get }
```

What I want is to create an exact replica of this property that is only available for versions lower than 9.0 so I do not have to check `if #available(iOS 9, *)` whenever I need to use this (or any other) property/method.

The best result I could get was the following:

```
extension String {

    @available(iOS 8.0, *)
    var localizedUppercaseString: String {

        return uppercaseStringWithLocale(NSLocale.currentLocale())
    }
}
```

With this, I can call `localizedUppercaseString`, no matter if the iOS version is 8.0 or 9.0. The problem is that this extension overrides the "original" property when executed with iOS 9.0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
extension String {

    var myLocalizedUppercaseString: String {
        if #available(iOS 9, *) {
            return localizedUppercaseString
        } else {
            return uppercaseStringWithLocale(NSLocale.currentLocale())
        }
    }
}
```

Now you just have to use `myLocalizedUppercaseString` property.

Comment: This is a good answer. If you are overriding the original localizedUppercaseString there's no way to get a localizedUppercaseString unless you implement it yourself, so you will need to use a custom instance var like @andriygordiychuk has suggested, or be comfortable with your own overriden implementation.

Comment: I was trying to avoid this solution as my intent is to use the "same" property, rather than a custom property.